# Where i make mistake here?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, nested

Hello everyone i have a problem with my code and i'm not sure how to do this , i need to write code that draw this in console:

[Draw '*' in every even number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox4BL.png)

For that i need to use nested loops.

So far i have only this:

```
var n = 5;
var stars = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var starsline = '';
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    console.log(i + j);
  }

  if ( i % 2 === 0){
    starsline += '2';
  } else {
    starsline += '1'
  }

  stars += starsline;
}

console.log(stars);
```

This numbers 2 and 1 are only to check if the number is even or odd.

Comment: The first step of successful debugging is code formatting. In your code its unclear which loop is inside of another. Indent those inner loops with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few things:

1) you got some weird bracket here:

```
 /*}*/ if ( i % 2 === 0){
```

which causes a syntax error later on.

2) you actually log the right thing:

```
 console.log(i + j)
```

but you dont use it. Just put that into your condition:

```
 if((i + j) % 2 === 0)
```

and you are done :)

---

```
 let size = 5, stars = "";
 for (var row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
   var starsline = "";
   for (var col = 1; col <= size; col++){
     if ((row + col) % 2 === 0){
       starsline += '*';
     } else {
       starsline += ' ';
   }
   stars += starsline + "\n";
 }
 console.log(stars);
```

Comment: @mariusz glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var n = 5;
var stars = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  var starsline = '';//<-- reset the value of line


   if ( i % 2 === 0)//<--this identifies which line will the stars be created
    {
        starsline += '* * *';//<--creating the stars on each line
    }
    else
    {
        starsline += ' * * ';//<--creating the stars on each line
    }
    stars += starsline+'\n';//<-- '\n' add line breaks for each lines
}
console.log(stars);//<-- print the stars
```

Comment: That's pretty much it :-)

Comment: `try this` is not an answer.

Comment: @JonasW. Stay positive mate. GOD BLESS. :)

Comment: That your answer is bad has nothing to do with my attitude towards life and god. I will be glad to remove my downvote (or even change it to an upvote) if you would [edit] and fix your answer, also providing an explanation.

Comment: @JonasW. Thank you for that. :) AND SORRY for my misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you tried to do is something like this:

```
var n = 5;
var stars = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var starsline = '';
    for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        if ( (i + j) % 2 === 0){
            // used three spaces for consistency in the drawing
            starsline += '   ';
        } else {
            starsline += ' * '
        }
    }
    stars += starsline + '\n';
}
console.log(stars);
```

Comment: That works perfect , thank you so much, anyways i found mistake in my code , i close second loop before if , that's why i can't get the correct results + " i + j " should be in " ( ) ", thank you so much :)